# How to list files in a directory on an https server

Tags: ruby, http

I have set up a connection with a rather large https server and I am able to download files if I know their name and location.

However, what I would like to do is search through the https file server and only pull out html files. I know how to do this in normal directories, but **is there a way to list out files and directories in an https file server** kinda like you would do an `ls` or `dir`?

I am unfamiliar with http servers in general so explanations are appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: This would probably do better on webmasters.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Is your question about accessing the files via a browser connection to the HTTPd server, or directly as files from a file-server?

Comment: I believe directly as files from a file server. This is the first time I've seen an http server used like this. It's a local area connection and can't be accessed outside of the office.

Comment: You should be able to access the files using Ruby's `Dir` and `IO` or `File` modules if it's a file server. It'd be the same as if you were using the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To list files, or be able to access them using HTTP from that list, you have to have a CGI, or some sort of plugin, that will give you a listing of the directories available.

That isn't something that is allowed by default as it can be a major security hole on a system. Imagine the problems someone could cause if they could browser through the `/etc` hierarchy on a *nix system and retrieve the password information, or through database files, etc.

So, by default no browsing of the file system is allowed. You can enable that many different ways, depending on the HTTPd server and the modules supplied with it or that have been added.

Writing such an interface isn't that hard either, but its better to rely on pre-built wheels, rather than reinvent your own.

Comment: Other than through ruby, I normally access the server through windows explorer and it will list files available. Is there a specific plug in that would allow this that I can take advantage of?

Comment: No browser can see files on a server unless there is something in the server allowing it to. That's just how the protocol and security works. If you are using Windows Explorer, then it has nothing to do with the host being a HTTPd server, it is only the fact you are mounting the HTTPd server as a file-server. That was not clear in your question at all.